# Pass Text from form to formula field

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I create a formula for conditional sum. Here is sample code.
`     if {Customer.Region}  = 'VA'
     then 1
     else 0

To sum records in the state of Virginia:

```
 if {Customer.Region}  = 'VA'
 then {Orders.Amount}
 else 0`
```

I want to input the value 'VA' from textbox of a form dynamically. When i input 'VA' in my form and click a button that value go to the formula if {Customer.Region}  = 'textbox Value'. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Parameter Field.  This will allow you to be prompted by the report to input a value.  So if you created a Parameter Field and name it "MyString", then you could do your comparison to your report field as:

```
If {Customer.Region} = {?MyString}
   //Do something if true
Else
   //Do something if false
```

Please note, this will only prompt you to input a value for the Parameter Field when the report is executed.  If you want to compare using a second input value, you will need to run the report again for each additional value.